# How to do it by Dominated Conversgence Theorem?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I'm trying to find the limit
$$ I = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac1{n} |f(x)|^2 x\cdot\nabla\chi (x/n)dx, $$
where $f \in H^1 (\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C)$, $f \in H^2_{loc}(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C)$ and $f \in L^\infty (\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C)$, the test function $\chi \in \mathrm C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R) $ such that $0\le \chi\le 1$ on $\mathbb R^d$, $\chi = 1$ on $B(0,1)$ and $\chi=0$ outside $B(0,2)$.

I hope to prove that $I=0$ by Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I don't know how to determine a dominator. Could someone give me a hint?

**Edit:** Thank to Nate Eldredge's comment, it seems not true without the assumptions $f \in L^\infty (\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C)$ and $f \in H^1 (\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C)$.

Comment: I assume the . between $x$ and $\nabla \chi$ is a dot product?  You can typeset it properly with `\cdot` (use the "edit" button to make changes).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the new assumption that $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the statement is true.  (The additional assumptions that $f \in L^\infty \cap H^2_{\mathrm{loc}}$ are not necessary.)

Integrating by parts we have:

$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac1{n} |f(x)|^2 x\cdot\nabla\chi (x/n)\,dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{n} \chi(x/n) (2 \operatorname{Re} [f(x) \nabla f(x) \cdot x] + d|f(x)|^2)\,dx.$$

Now let us estimate the integrand (call it $h_n(x)$).  By Cauchy-Schwarz (for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ dot product) we have
$$|h_n(x)| \le \frac{1}{n} \chi(x/n) (2 |f(x)| |\nabla f(x)| |x| + d|f(x)|^2).$$
When $|x| > 2n$ we have $\chi(x/n) = 0$ so we can assume $|x| \le 2n$, giving
$$\begin{align*} |h_n(x)| &\le \chi(x/n) \left(4 |f(x)| |\nabla f(x)| + \frac{d}{n} |f(x)|^2\right) \\ &\le 4 |f(x)| |\nabla f(x)| + d|f(x)|^2\end{align*}$$
since $|\chi| \le 1$ and $n \ge 1$.  Since $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we have $|f|, |\nabla f| \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, so $|f|^2, |f||\nabla f| \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the latter by Cauchy-Schwarz for the $L^2$ inner product.  Hence the last line above can be used as a dominating function

---

Under the original assumption, $f \in H^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the claim is not true.  For example, take $n=1$ and $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ x^{47}, & x \ge 0 \end{cases}$$
which is $C^2$ (indeed, $C^{46}$) and thus in $H^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^1)$.  Now if we integrate by parts we  get
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{n} |f(x)|^2 x \chi'(x/n)\,dx &= -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{n} \chi(x/n) (2 f(x) f'(x) x + |f(x)|^2)\,dx \\
&\le -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{n} \chi(x/n) |f(x)|^2\,dx 
\end{align*}$$
since $f(x) f'(x) x \ge 0$ everywhere.  Now since $\chi \ge 0$ and $\chi = 1$ for $0 \le x \le n$ we have
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{n} \chi(x/n) |f(x)|^2\,dx \le -\int_0^n \frac{1}{n} |f(x)|^2\,dx = -\frac{n^{94}}{95} \to -\infty$$
by direct computation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Nate Eldredge. Perhaps, you are right. In fact, I'm trying to get some identity for my problem thank to some kind of limit like this. So, maybe I need more assumptions, for example $f\in L^\infty (\mathbb R^d, \mathbb C)$. Is it true now? 
I'm sorry if it makes you lose time.

Comment: @AkaiShuichi: My suspicion is that $L^\infty$ will not work either, because $f'$ may become large near infinity.  I would try a counterexample like $\sin(x^k)$ for large $k$.  It will work if you have $f \in H^1$, however (globally, not just locally).

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge: It means It will be OK if $f\in L^\infty, f\in H^1$ and $f\in H^2_{loc}$? Could you please prove it for this case?

Comment: @AkaiShuichi: Done.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great solution! Just a small mistake I think: you should write $d|f(x)|^2$ after integrating by parts, due to $\nabla\cdot x = d $.

Comment: @AkaiShuichi: Thanks, corrected.